# Is it possible to use a nodejs worker for both scheduling and listening

Tags: node.js

Built a nodejs application to take advantage of multi-core systems using cluster of Node processes  and all workers are listening on port 3002. On top of listening to port, I tried to schedule jobs on all workers at regular intervals to receive messages from Queue( ex: amazon SQS) . This resulted dying of workers  during execution of scheduled tasks.

Can we use a worker for both scheduling and listening ?

```
{"eid":"1440263352155-39077","description":"Polling for messages","level":"debug","message":"","timestamp":"2015-08-22T17:09:12.155Z"}
{"eid":"1440263359093-21470","description":"Received SQS response [object Object]","level":"debug","message":"","timestamp":"2015-08-22T17:09:19.093Z"}
{"eid":"1440263359111-30019","description":"Worker 873 died :(","level":"debug","message":"","timestamp":"2015-08-22T17:09:19.111Z"}
```

Comment: If you're running all workers on the same server, I don't see how you can have them all listening on 3002.

Comment: @jfriend00 The `cluster` module can operate in two ways: the master listens on the port and sends requests to workers, *or* the master creates the socket and passes it to all workers that can then bind to the same port to accept connections directly (the OS handles the connection distribution which may not always be efficient).

Comment: Yes, [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) is here based on cpu count

Comment: If your workers are dying unexpectedly, they are most likely crashing. You should try to find out why.